# Finding the values of C such that $\ln(x^2)-x^2 + C \geq 0$

Tags: inequality

I have the solution of an equation as $y=\pm \sqrt{\ln(x^2)-x^2 + C}$. I am asked to find the values of $C$ the solution is valid for.

So I get this inequality $\ln(x^2)-x^2+C \geq 0$. How can I find the values of $C$ such that $C\geq x^2 - \ln(x^2)$.

I know that $x\neq 0$ to avoid the infinity value of the logarithm function and the root must be zero or positive.

Comment: I think such a $C$ cannot exist. :) See my answer for the explanations.

Comment: $f(x)=x^2-2\log|x|$ is not a bounded function. There are no constants $C$ allowing $\sqrt{\log(x^2)-x^2+C}$ to make sense for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio. Could you explain what happens when $f(x)=x^2-2\log|x|$ is not a bounded function, so that you know that $C$ doesn't exist?

Comment: @LukeJt.  If such a $C$ existed, then $f$ would've been bounded from the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want to have $\ln(x^2)-x^2+C \geq 0$

Write $C$ as $\ln(K)$ for $K=e^{C}$ and then combine it with $\ln(x^2)$.

$\ln(K) + \ln(x^2) = \ln(Kx^2) \geq x^2$

Since $f(x)=e^x$ is a strictly increasing function, we could apply it to both sides of the inequality to obtain:

$$Kx^2 \geq e^{x^2} \implies K \geq \frac{e^{x^2}}{x^2}$$

Since $C$ is independent of $x$ and the above inequality is valid for every $x$ in the domain of the expression $\ln(x^2)-x^2+C$, you could take limits of both sides of the inequality when $x \to 0$ and you'd get $K \geq +\infty$. Therefore, such a $C$ does not exist.

If this proof is confusing for you, note that $x^2-\ln(x^2) \leq C$ is the same as saying that $C$ is an upper bound for $f(x)=x^2-\ln(x^2)$. But $x \to \pm\infty$ implies $f(x)\to +\infty$ and $x \to 0$ implies $f(x) \to -\infty$. Therefore, the function $f$ is unbounded. And the reason for $f(x) \to +\infty$ when $x \to \pm \infty$ that is that the rate of growth of $\ln(x^2)$ as $x$ gets large is too slow to be able to catch $x^2$. The last statement about comparing the rates of growth of two functions is intuitive and even though it's not rigorous, it's commonly used in calculus without proof.

Comment: The given solution is for $C > 1$.

Comment: @LukeJt.  Then the given solution is wrong. Take $C=2$ and evaluate $\ln(x^2)-x^2+2$ at $x=0.1$ which is not even a small number. :) The value of the expression is negative and it's approximately equal to $-2.615$. In fact, such a $C$ does not exist.

Comment: Ok. Could you please explain why $f(x)=e^x$ needs to be a strictly increasing function to apply it to both sides of the inequality? I'd like to understand it.Or give me some key words to find the explanation in google?

Comment: @LukeJt.  Sure. It's actually because of the definition of a strictly increasing function that we're allowed to apply it to the above inequality. The definition is $x < y \implies f(x) < f(y)$. If $f$ is not a monotone function, you can't apply it to both sides of an inequality because you don't know what it does to an inequality. If $f$ were a decreasing function instead, then the inequality had to be reversed because $x < y \implies f(x) > f(y)$ for a strictly decreasing function. One-to-one functions have to be either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing. Do you know why?

Comment: I guess it has to do with injectivity. Could you explain it, to have a clearer idea?

Comment: @LukeJt.  In general, whenever you have an inequality, you have to be very careful when you want to apply a function to both sides of it because unfavorable things can happen. For example, look at $\sin(x)$ which is an innocent looking periodic function. $\pi/2 <\pi \implies \sin(\pi/2) > \sin(\pi)$ while $3\pi/2 < 2\pi \implies \sin(3\pi/2) < \sin(2\pi)$. Do you see the problem we have?

Comment: @LukeJt.  You are right. The injectivity will fail if the function is not **strictly** increasing or decreasing. For example, if $f$ is just an increasing function, but not a strictly increasing one, you might have $x < y$, but get $f(x) = f(y)$. For injective functions that cannot happen.

Comment: @stressed-out.I don't see the problem quite clearly. Could you please explain it. I'd really like to understand it too.

Comment: @LukeJt. The problem is that the behavior of $\sin(x)$ is unpredictable on $\mathbb{R}$. Sometimes it's preserving the order, sometimes it's reversing it. In the former case, it's reversing it, in the latter case it's actually preserving it! That's the problem. Unless we ensure that $\sin(.)$ is monotone on the interval that our inequality falls inside, we can't apply $\sin(.)$ to it in general. . For example, $\sin(x)$ is strictly increasing in the interval $[-\pi/2,+\pi/2]$. Therefore, $0 < x < \pi/2 \implies 0 < \sin(x) < 1$. But when monotonicity fails, we'll be clueless.

Comment: I don't know if you can give an example of an inequality multiplied by a non monotonous function where one can see that the inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: @LukeJt.  I did give you an example. That's why I talked about $\sin(x)$ all along. For example, when $0<x<\pi$, applying $\sin(x)$ gives you $0<\sin(x)<0$ which is absolutely absurd. :)

Comment: Thanks. I meant an example more like this one with the $arcsin(x)$ and $sin(x)$, but with functions that doesn't need to be the inverse of each other.   http://math.feld.cvut.cz/mt/txtz/0/txe3za0a.htm

Comment: First of all, please note that $\sin(x)$ does **NOT** have an inverse on $(0,\pi)$ and you should know why! :)  Secondly, maybe using $f(x)=x^2$ would be easier for you.  $-1 < 1$ but if you square both sides, you'll get $1 < 1$ which is false. I don't know what part of it is still confusing for you. So, tell me what part of what I'm saying is hard to understand exactly and I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Thanks. I' ll think about it for a while. There's one thing you said before " sometimes it's preserving the order, sometimes it's reversing it. " What do you mean with that? The order of what?

Comment: @LukeJt. I meant the usual order of real numbers. The way that the real numbers are arranged and we say this one is larger than than one and so on. Saying $x<y$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ is called an order on real numbers. And I think the meanings of the verbs "to preserve" and "to reverse" are clear.

Comment: You mean than the domain goes in one direction and its images in the opposite direction? $\pi/2 <\pi \implies \sin(\pi/2) > \sin(\pi)$

Comment: @LukeJt. Exactly.

Comment: @LukeJt. You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show that $\log(x^2) - x^2 \leq -1$?

However, as $x \to \infty$, $\log(x^2) - x^2 \to -\infty$ and you can't make it non-negative by adding a constant $C$

What is the domain of $x$? If $x$ is bounded, then such a constant $C$ might exist, depending on the maximum value of $x$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \ln(x^2)-x^2$. Then $f'(x)=\frac{2x}{x^2}-2x=0$ for stationary points.

So $\frac1x=x \implies x = \pm 1$. As $f''(x)=-\frac2{x^2}-2<0$, a maximum exists.

Now $f(\pm 1) = \ln((\pm 1)^2)-(\pm 1)^2=-1$ so global maximum is $-1$. Hence a solution/solutions exist when $C \ge 1$.

Comment: I think this is incorrect. Take $g(x)=\ln(x^2)-x^2+1$. i.e. when $C=1$. Then $g(0.1) \approx -3.615$  according to wolfram alpha.

Comment: In general, you cannot find the "global" maximum or minimum of a function defined on an unbounded (or even an open) domain just by differentiating. Differentiation is a local operator. $\pm 1$ are local maxima. That's where your argument fails.

Comment: @stressed-out Does the solution have to be valid for all $x$?

Comment: Yes, because the expression is under square root and it won't make sense if it's not positive.

Comment: If $C=1$ then for $x = \pm 1$, $y=\pm \sqrt{0} = 0$ so there is a solution.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. You want to have a function by having an expression under square root and you want it to be non-negative to be meaningful. As I said, when $C=1$, $g(0.1) < 0$.